# Writing a query returning all members of a hierarchy

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchy

I'm having trouble writing a query that seems rather complicated for my level.

The problem is easy: it uses only one table `ressources(id_ressource, name, id_manager)`

As you may guess, `id_manager` refers to an other `id_ressource`. What I want is to get a list of all ressources under a specific manager. But a manager might by the manager of others managers and so on: I want to get all those ressources under him, including managers themselves.

So far the query I have is most simple:

```
SELECT name FROM ressources WHERE id_manager = :MANAGER_VAR;
```

I know I might be using some of `CONNECT BY, PRIOR`, but I have almost no experience with it and would gladly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hierarchical query (`connect by`) looks like this:

```
select  name
from    ressources               --  check your spelling?
start   with id_ressource = :manager_var
connect by   id_manager   = prior id_ressource
;
```

Here `:manager_var` is the input variable (bind variable, as in your attempt).

Comment: Ok I see it seems simpler than recursive queries. Thanks for this, now I have both methods which is truly fine.

Answer (score 1):

Starting in Oracle 11gR2 you can use standard Recursive CTEs instead of the old `CONNECT BY`.

For example:

```
with
n (id_ressource, name, id_manager) as (
  select * from resources where id_manager = 123 -- starting point
 union all
  select r.*
  from n
  join ressources r on r.id_manager = n.id_ressource
)
select * from n
```

Comment: That was what I was looking for. Nicely done, thank you! I did not know we could do recursive queries like this, it's beautiful.

Comment: Please note, though, that for queries where `connect by` works just as well as recursive queries, `connect by` is **much** faster. That is entirely understandable; recursive queries are much more flexible and powerful than `connect by`, but that comes with significant overhead. When the additional overhead is not needed, it is best avoided.

Comment: @mathguy I think I read a similar comment from you before and I didn't remember who wrote it anymore. If it were you, can you provide some info, article, or documentation about this? I would like to learn more details. Thank you.

Comment: See this for a timed test: https://community.oracle.com/thread/4186434?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

Should work for `CONNECT BY` (my Oracle knowledge is a bit rusty). Assuming you've got a table with employees relationships: `employees(id_employee, id_manager)`

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.name
FROM ressources r
JOIN employees e on r.id_manager = e.id_employee
START WITH r.id_manager = :MANAGER_VAR
CONNECT BY PRIOR e.id_employee= r.id_manager
```

Comment: Unfortunately I need to not use a relationship table.

Comment: Then how do you know that some person is a manager for another person? Do you treat them as a "resourse"

Comment: Yeah you know it if that person has id_manager = another_id. But don't worry @The Impaler got me. Thanks for your help !

Comment: Your Oracle seems OK, what is off is your understanding of the data. The relationships are all in a single table: employee id = 1403 (for example), id_manager = 3438. Then 3438 also appears in the employee id column - and that row also has an id_manager (whoever 3438's manager is). Etc. There is no need for two tables here.